# how to divide a string, I mean convert 1234567890 into 12:34:56:78:90

Tags: regex, string, macos, perl

I need convert some Mac Numbers(00163e2fbab7) into Mac String. (with ":")

Is there some good way to divide the Mac Number into group? I mean into (00),(16),(3e),(2f),(ba),(b7)

I know, there is a `where` function in [*`List::Gen`*](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen) but I can't install this package in my host. So, how can I do that?

### Thank you very much!

Comment: "I can't install this package in my host" - oh you can. See https://metacpan.org/release/local-lib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $mac = "00163e2fbab7";
$mac =~ s/..(?!$)\K/:/g;
print "$mac\n";
```

Output:

```
00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7
```

If you don't have Perl 5.10, you can use:

```
$mac =~ s/(..)(?!$)/$1:/g;
```

Comment: Using `$&` slows down every non-capturing regex in the process. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. I didn't get `\K` to work, but I realise I'm using `v5.8.5` (*shudder*) on this computer, and `\K` was new in `v5.10.0`.

Comment: 5.8.5 was released in July 2004. Please update to something more recent :/

Comment: @flesk, Added pre-5.10 version that doesn't use `$&`. 5.8 and 5.10 are no longer supported, and 5.12's days are numbered as 5.16's release is approaching rapidly.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. The `5.8` is my work environment, and I don't have much control over that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

If you know you're dealing with MAC addresses, use a library which is designed specifically for them, like [`Net::MAC`](http://search.cpan.org/~karlward/Net-MAC-1.1/lib/Net/MAC.pm)

Answer (score 6):

Just split the string into two-character chunks and use `join` to put them back together. Like this

```
my $mac = "00163e2fbab7";
print join ':', $mac =~ /../g;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7
```

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) will print the address in multiple [formats](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/functions/sprintf.html).

```
my ($addr,$delim,$fmt) = (q(00163e2fbab7),q(:),q(2x));
printf qq(%*v0$fmt\n),$delim, pack(q(c*),(map { hex } 
(unpack(qq(A2) x int(length($addr)/2),$addr))));
```

**OUTPUT** with formatting options

- `00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7` **hex** lower-case when `$fmt = q(2x)`.
- `00:16:3E:2F:BA:B7` **hex** upper-case when `$fmt = q(2X)`.
- `000:022:062:047:186:183` **integer** when `$fmt = q(3i)`.
- `000:026:076:057:272:267` **octal** when `$fmt = q(3o)`.
- `00000000:00010110:00111110:00101111:10111010:10110111` **binary** when `$fmt = q(8b)`.
- `:XXII:LXII:XLVII:CLXXXVI:CLXXXIII` **roman numerals** when `just kidding`.